# Linear order preserving syntactic trees

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, word-order

Two questions:

- Is the syntactic tree notation supposed to be

  1. Linear order preserving in general
  2. Linear order preserving for English
  3. Generally linear order preserving for English
  4. None of the above

By "linear order preserving" I mean *for any sentence, producing a syntax tree where the order of leaves corresponds to one permitted in speech*. I understand that this will depend on your syntactic theory, so I'm open to different proposals. In particular, I'm also interested in answers to the following question:

- Which syntactic theories produce the most linear order preserving
  trees?

Comment: I've never seen or heard of a syntactic tree that *doesn't* preserve linear order (unless you count those 'deep structures' in Chomskyan theories). In fact one of the first things we learnt in class about syntax trees is that they express linear order through the order of the leaves...

Comment: @WavesWashSands Movement breaks this, though: consider inversion in English questions, or V2 word order in German. (Assuming you're referring to the underlying structure, not the surface structure.)

Comment: @Draconis I did write 'unless you count those 'deep structures' in Chomskyan theories' in my original comment.

Comment: @WavesWashSands You might make this into an answer, describing (the difference between) the respective theories

Comment: Phrase structures are order-preserving. Dependency trees also preserve the surface order of words in all sane theories.

Comment: If you want your tree diagrams to have leaves with left-right order on the page corresponding to left-right order in pronunciation, you need to say so.  It's a notational option, and a matter of convenience, not theory.

Comment: @GregLee "corresponds to one permitted in speech" should make this clear enough (have you encountered a right-to-left correspondence between leaves and speech?)

Comment: I haven't enountered a right-to-left  correspondence, jaam, but I could make one up at any time.  It's just a convention.  Why should anyone care about this?

Comment: @GregLee Since they obviously care, this sounds like a question to you